# Receiving a country of an ip address from a website does not working (Python)

Tags: python, http, get, pycharm, ip

I tried to do something like this:

```
import json
import requests

def get_country_by_ip(ip):

    # Create a get request to receive the country of the ip from the website 'ipinfo.io'
    endpoint = f'https://ipinfo.io/{ip}/json'
    response = requests.get(endpoint, verify = True)

    # Check if the request succeeds and return the country according to this condition
    if response.status_code == HTTP_SUCCESS_CODE:
            data = response.json()
            print(data)
            return data['country'] # Return the correct field that we need

    return "Request failed. Error code: " + str(response.status_code)
```

But my error is: **KeyError: 'country'**

There are any thoughts or ideas that you can advise me?

Comment: maybe you did not proivide a valid ip?

Comment: Or maybe you are accessing from 127.0.0.1, or other local address which doesn’t have a location